# xpath - using contains with a wildcard

Tags: xpath, pattern-matching

I have the following, and trying to see if there's a better approach. I know it cn be done using starts-with/contains. I'm testing with firefox 10, which I believe implements xpath 2.+.

Test node is

```
<a id="foo">
.
.
.
<a id="foo1">
.
<a id="foo2">
```

Is there a way to use wildcards to be able to get the foo1/foo2 nodes..

Something like

```
//a[@id =* 'foo'] 

or 

//a[contains(@id*,'foo')]
```

Which would say, give me the "a" where the id starts with "foo" but has additional chars... This would then skip the 1st node with the "foo"

I thought I had seen an rticle on this, but can't find it!

As I recall, the article stated that xpath had a set of operators that could be used to designate the start/end of a given pattern in a string.

thanks

Comment: `*=` (not `=*`) is used in JQuery, not XPath.

Answer (score 11):

**Use**:

```
//a[@id[starts-with(., 'foo') and string-length() > 3]]
```

Comment: A parenthesis is missing after `starts-with`. The whole expression should read: `//a[@id[starts-with(., 'foo') and string-length() > 3]]`.

Answer (score 6):

Not a wildcard, but probably what you need nonetheless:

```
//a[(@id!='foo') and starts-with(@id,'foo')]
```

See [W3C XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with).