# Selenium: Why run 2 instances of Firefox?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, geckodriver

I have console log:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: E:\github\donhuvy\linkedin_crawler
Staring get info user LinkedIn.
Staring get info user LinkedIn.
1594200496318   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\MinhPhuc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileI0zaWu"
1594200496318   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\MinhPhuc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile3e8imo"
```

[image]

I have code

```
using linkedin_mp.Data;
using linkedin_mp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace linkedin_mp.Controllers
{
    // https://localhost:44360/weatherforecast
    // https://localhost:5001/linkedin/crawl
    // https://localhost:5001/linkedin/profiles
    // https://localhost:5001/linkedin/getprofile

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LinkedInController : ControllerBase
    {

        public LinkedInController() : base()
        {

        }

        public static void Login()
        {

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("crawl")]
        public IEnumerable<WordNode> Crawl()
        {
            List<WordNode> list2 = new List<WordNode>();
            // Console.WriteLine("Start crawling.");
            // Gọi chương trình bởi API call.
            // Lấy danh sách user_id từ database.
            // Điền thông tin dữ liệu vào database.
            // Điền thông tin version 2 vào database.
            // So sánh (diff) dữ liệu 2 version.
            // Trả về dữ liệu diff.

            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine("Staring crawling LinkedIn.");
            using IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/");
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("nav__button-secondary")).SendKeys(Keys.Return);

        // driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("xx@outlook.com");
        // driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("xx" + Keys.Enter);

        // driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("yyy@gmail.com");
        // driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("yyy" + Keys.Enter);


        Entry:
            // driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/in/loan-duong-567779189/");
            string randomLink = getRandomLink();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(randomLink);
            // Lấy tên user.
            // IWebElement webElement = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]")));
            // Console.WriteLine(webElement.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim());

            // Get linked connection blocks.
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489638/3728901
            // IEnumerable<IWebElement> connectionBlocks = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@data-control-name=browsemap_profile]"));
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399982/3728901
            IEnumerable<IWebElement> connectionBlocks = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@id[starts-with(., 'ember') and string-length() > 5]]"));

            int connectionBlocksTotal = connectionBlocks.ToList().Count;

            Console.WriteLine("1. Có từng này block được tìm thấy: " + connectionBlocksTotal);

            for (int i = 0; i < connectionBlocksTotal; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">> " + i + ". Parsing per block.");
                string link = (connectionBlocks.ToList())[i].GetAttribute("href").Trim();
                // If link string is LinkiedIn profile URL.
                if (isLinkedInProfileURL(link))
                {
                    Profile p2 = new Profile
                    {
                        Version = 1,
                        LinkedinUrl = link,
                        Created = DateTime.Now,
                        Modified = DateTime.Now
                    };
                    ApplicationDbContext dbContext2 = new ApplicationDbContext();
                    var profile = from p in dbContext2.Profile
                                  where p.LinkedinUrl == link
                                  select p;
                    if (profile.FirstOrDefault() == null)
                    {
                        dbContext2.Add(p2);
                        dbContext2.SaveChangesAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine("Thứ tự >>" + i + "Save " + link + " to database success.");
                    }
                }
            }
            goto Entry;

            // driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("cheese" + Keys.Enter);
            // IWebElement firstResult = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("h3>div")));
            //Console.WriteLine(firstResult.GetAttribute("textContent"));

            //Profile p1 = new Profile
            //{
            //    Version = 1,
            //    LinkedinUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/vy-donhu-9a46a91b1x/"
            //};
            //ApplicationDbContext2 dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext2();
            //dbContext.Add(p1);
            //dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Console.WriteLine("4. End of program.");
            ///////////////////////////////////////////

            return list2;
        }

        // https://github.com/lorey/social-media-profiles-regexs#linkedin

        /// <summary>
        /// Check an URL is LinkedIn profile URL. For example: https://www.linkedin.com/in/stephy-le-793399195/ 
        /// is valid.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="linkedInProfileURL"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool isLinkedInProfileURL(string linkedInProfileURL)
        {
            string[] prefixes = { "https://www.linkedin.com/in/" };
            string[] suffixes = { "/recent-activity/", "/detail/", "/contact-info/" };
            // Các kết quả như thế này cần loại bỏ:
            // https://www.linkedin.com/in/123linhphuong/detail/recent-activity/

            bool resultPrefix = prefixes.Any(prefix => linkedInProfileURL.StartsWith(prefix));
            bool resultSuffix = !suffixes.Any(suffix => linkedInProfileURL.EndsWith(suffix));

            // string ruleProfile = @"(?:https?:)?\/\/(?:[\w]+\.)?linkedin\.com\/in\/(?P<permalink>[\w\-\_À-ÿ%]+)\/?";
            // Regex re = new Regex(ruleProfile);     
            // return resultPrefix && resultSuffix && re.IsMatch(linkedInProfileURL);
            return resultPrefix && resultSuffix;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Đếm tổng số bản ghi.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int countNumberOfRecords()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var profile = from p in applicationDbContext.Profile
                          select p;
            if (profile.FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int totalRecord = profile.ToList().Count();
                Console.WriteLine("Tổng số bản ghi: " + totalRecord);
                return totalRecord;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Lấy một liên kết ngẫu nhiên.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string getRandomLink()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext dbContext2 = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var profile = from p in dbContext2.Profile
                          select p;
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(0, countNumberOfRecords());
            string randomLink = ((Profile)profile.ToList()[randomNumber]).LinkedinUrl;
            Console.WriteLine("Link ngẫu nhiên được chọn: " + randomLink);
            return randomLink;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// List all LinkedIn profiles.
        /// URL: https://localhost:5001/linkedin/profiles
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("profiles")]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetAllProfiles()
        {        
            ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var links = from p in dbContext.Profile
                          select p.LinkedinUrl;
            return links.ToList<string>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a specific profile information.
        /// URL: https://localhost:5001/linkedin/getprofile
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getprofile")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get2()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();   

            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine("Staring get info user LinkedIn.");

            // Bat buoc phai load profile dang su dung;

            //string PROFILE_DIR = "D://tmp//linkedin_tien";
            // FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(PROFILE_DIR);
            FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
            firefoxProfile.SetPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
            firefoxProfile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25");
            FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            //firefoxOptions.Profile = firefoxProfile;

            //firefoxOptions.SetPreference("permissions.default.stylesheet", 2);
            // firefoxOptions.SetPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
            // firefoxOptions.SetPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so", false);

            // using IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/");

            // driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("xx@outlook.com");
            // driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("xx" + Keys.Enter);
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("nav__button-secondary")).SendKeys(Keys.Return);
                //driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("gg@sis.hust.edu.vn");
                //driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("gg" + Keys.Enter);

                driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("xx@outlook.com");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("xx" + Keys.Enter);
            }
            catch {}            

            ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var profilesList = from p in dbContext.Profile
                               //where p.Id >= 425 && p.Id <=528 
                               where p.ProfileName == null
                               select p;
            List<Profile> profiles = profilesList.ToList<Profile>();
            List<string> links = new List<string>();
            int count = profiles.Count();

            //ApplicationDbContext dbContext2 = new ApplicationDbContext();

            for (int i = 0; i < profiles.Count(); i++)            
            // for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)            
            {
                string url = profiles[i].LinkedinUrl;
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
                Console.WriteLine("url = " + url);
                //Profile profile = new Profile();
                Profile profile = profiles[i];

                // profile.Id = profiles[i].Id;
                Console.WriteLine("id = " + profile.Id);

                IWebElement webElement1 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("li.inline.t-24.t-black.t-normal.break-words")));
                string profile_name = webElement1.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("profile_name = " + profile_name);
                profile.ProfileName = profile_name;

                // profile_headline
                try
                {
                    IWebElement webElement2 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("h2.mt1")));
                    string profile_headline = webElement2.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                    Console.WriteLine("profile_headline = " + profile_headline);
                    profile.ProfileHeadline = profile_headline;
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                // short_address
                IWebElement webElement3 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("li.t-16.t-black.t-normal.inline-block")));
                string short_address = webElement3.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("sort_address = " + short_address);
                profile.ProfileAddress = short_address;
                profile.Created = DateTime.Now;
                profile.Modified = DateTime.Now;

                //dbContext2.Profile.Update(profile);
                //dbContext2.SaveChangesAsync();
                dbContext.Profile.Update(profile);
                dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Save to table [Profile] success.");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");

                // profile_address . đang sai
                // IWebElement webElement4 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("h2.mt1")));
                // Console.WriteLine("profile_address = " + webElement4.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim());

                // full_address. chưa lấy được từ pop-up.
                // IWebElement webElement5 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@id[starts-with(., 'ember')]/div/section[2]/div/a")));
                // Console.WriteLine(webElement5.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim());
            }
            try
            {
                // temp profile directory path? --> folder watcher;
                // Copy temp profile --> PROFILE_DIR --> bypass file: parent.lock

                driver.Close();

            }
            catch { }
            return list;
        }

    }

}
```

I place debug point at lines

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

I seen 2 instances of Firefox opened.

I want only 1 instance of Firefox, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two different FF instantiations in your code.

You mention you've put brekpoints on one:
In `public IEnumerable<string> Get2()` you have: `IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

But you also have this one:
In `public IEnumerable<WordNode> Crawl()` you have `using IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

If you want just one Firefox consolidate it to one instantiation.
Something like creating a property to hold your driver object and instantiate it in the constructor or in a [setup] if your using a unit testing framework. Then remove the other FF instantiations and update all your driver references to this new object.

This depends on how your running your code and if you want parallelization. If you just want a single thread, try something like this:

```
    public class LinkedInController : ControllerBase
    {

    private IWebDriver driver;

        public LinkedInController() : base()
        {
            //Also do any options stuff here
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

//...all your other code
```

If you've got multiple classes that are using selenium - you should also move the creation and management of your driver object to it's own class. You don't want to start copying and pasting all the driver options into multiple locations.

Comment: no, it is crawling, not testing. This is MVC model.

Comment: Consider creating your FF driver outside of this class in a static property.  -  Or are you saying that when you run the single line with your brekapoint on `IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` in `get2()` that creates 2 isntances of FF?